# URL scheme "prefs:root=PASS" iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, url, ios10, url-scheme

I know there are lot of topics about this problem but is there a solution? I have not found official documentation for that.

My problem is I need to redirect my code on storage settings like this : (work in iOS 9)

```
 let settingsUrl = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP")
       if let url = settingsUrl {
           UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
        }
```

But since ios10 this method don't work, so Is there an alternative? I saw SnapChat, Google Maps redirect their apps to different part on settings (not the main screen of settings) so I think there is a solution.

I already implement the url scheme in info.plist but it's still not work
[image: I already implement the url scheme but it's still not work]

I tried this method but same issue too

```
let settingsUrl = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP")
        if let url = settingsUrl {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL.init(string:"Prefs:root=General&path=STORAGE_ICLOUD_USAGE/DEVICE_STORAGE")!, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionUniversalLinksOnly:true], completionHandler:{(success: Bool?) -> Void in})

            } else {
                 UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
            }
        }
```

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since iOS 10, it's not possible to open the `Settings` app from a third party app. The only settings that are allowed to be opened are Keyboard setting but only by a custom keyboard extension and your own application settings.
More details: [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/146658#146658)

**Note:** Even for iOS 9, using the URL string that is mentioned in the question can lead to app rejection as it violates [iOS App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).